# Mounting a file system using a C program

Tags: mount, linux-kernel, gpio

In my initramfs.cpio I have only these directories:

```
root@localhost extract]# ls 
dev  init  tmp sys
```

dev has console and sys is empty.

init is a binary corresponding to program that I discussed in [Accessing GPIO after kernel boots](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125550/accessing-gpio-after-kernel-boots).

Now in the same GPIO program I would like to write code  to mount a /sys. I understand it can be mounted using mount:

```
mount -t sysfs none /sys
```

How do I write a C program that will implement the above line. Please note that I do not have a file system; initramfs.cpio has empty folders: /sys, /tmp. I can put more empty folder if required. But I cannot put full file system.

**My main intention** 
To access GPIO using this [program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125550/accessing-gpio-after-kernel-boots) or otherwise, but without using a full file system.
I dont need any other thing to run, but just want GPIO access (and LED blink)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use the `mount(2)` system call. From the manpage:

> ### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   #include <sys/mount.h>
>
>   int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
>             const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
>             const void *data);
> ```

So, in your C code, that'd look something like:

```c
#include <sys/mount.h>

/* ... */

void mount_sys() {
    if (0 != mount("none", "/sys", "sysfs", 0, "")) {
        /* handle error */
    }
}
```

(That last empty string is where you'd pass mount options, but AFAIK sysfs doesn't take any.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. "It's possible" refers to what?

Comment: @user2799508 It refers to I haven't actually tested to make sure passing a NULL doesn't result in an error... If it gives an error, I'd try the empty string.

Comment: You are very smart. your solution worked!! I just need to put "" instead of NULL. thanks

Comment: @user2799508 Glad to hear it worked. Thanks for the heads up that "" is needed instead of NULL, I've edited it in.